# What is the fastest way to send a small video from one iOS device to another?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, video, file-transfer

I'd like to make an application in which one person takes a short video, maybe five to twenty seconds in length, and sends it to another user as quickly as possible. An example would be an instant replay at a sporting event. What would be the fastest and most reliable way to transfer a video of that size? I am considering the following two options, but am open to other suggestions.

- uploading the video to my own server and performing some kind of push operation
- performing a direct transfer over a shared wifi network (what about long distance?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd take your first option

1. Record your video and compress it to a reasonable size on the source device.
2. Upload the video to an external server.
3. From the server, send push notifications to the particular users who should be able view the video.

If recipients/consumers of the video could stream the uploaded video from the server it would be a pretty reasonable user experience.

Comment: or you could do it via NFC. ooh that's right ios doesn't have that :P

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that it would be important to allow the user to scrub through the video at their own pace, an I'm not sure if streaming would significantly impact that capability.

Comment: @jere what about the 9million devices without NFC?

Comment: @GoldenJoe Go and stream a video and see if you can scrub it. I think you might have some research to do regarding sending video over the air.